# Flutter Firebase: Bad state: Snapshot has neither data nor error

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-realtime-database

i am trying to get from the table Products, the specific products that the P_ID is added to cart
now the code beneath work well but only retrieve one element

```
final Stream<QuerySnapshot> cart = FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('products')
        .where('pid', isEqualTo: cartitems[0])
        .snapshots();
```

however it doesn't work when I do it like this

```
Stream<QuerySnapshot>? cart;
for (var i = 0; i < cartitems.length; i++) {
  cart = FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection('products')
      .where('pid', isEqualTo: cartitems[i])
      .snapshots();
}
```

it gives me this error

> The following StateError was thrown building StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot<Object?>>(dirty, state: _StreamBuilderBaseState<QuerySnapshot<Object?>, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot<Object?>>>#9ea5d):
> Bad state: Snapshot has neither data nor error

> The relevant error-causing widget was:
> StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot<Object?>> StreamBuilder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using a Stream Builder instead to achieve the same effect without a for loop.  Stream Builder will automatically take out all of the cart items you have stored in firebase.  To get rid of the snapshot error, implement the if statements below.

```
final CollectionReference cart = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('products');
child: StreamBuilder(
        stream: cart
            .where('pid', isEqualTo: cartitems)
            .snapshots();
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) { 
        if (!snapshot.hasData) {
            return const Text('Loading...');
        } 
        if (snapshot.hasError) {
            return const Text('Something went wrong.');
        }
```